# Setting up require.js for a static website and loading custom code

Tags: javascript, require.js

I am a new SO/SE user and I initially asked this question on SO, but i was 'sent' here -for some reason i don't clearly understand but anyway- so here I am..! I was actually curious about my require.js setup, cause it is the  first time I 'm using it and having seen many different approaches/examples, I am not sure if what I 've done so far is correct. 
So, on my index I have on the "head"

```
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/vendor/require-2.2.0-min.js"></script>
```

and at the end of my 'body' I have the Google Analytics snippet. No other script is loaded directly from index.

On app.js that is inside my $projectroot/js folder I have:

```
requirejs.config({
   "baseUrl": "js/vendor",
   "paths": {
      "app": "..",
      "jquery" : ['//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min','jquery-1.12.4.min'],
      "modernizr" : 'modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min',
      "bootstrap" : ['//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min','bootstrap.min'],
      "plugins": '../plugins'
    },
    "shim": {
       "bootstrap": ["jquery"],
       "plugins": ["bootstrap"]
    }
});

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

Also, my main.js which is on the same folder with app.js contains:

```
define([
   "jquery",
   "modernizr",
   "bootstrap",
   "plugins"
], function($)
{
$(function()
{
console.log('required plugins loaded...');
});
});
```

Finally, my plugins.js (again, on the same folder with main.js and app.js) is NOT a library, but some custom js code that I need to be loaded last. Is this ok so far? Any drawbacks with this approach? Would it be ok to add the rest of my custom js code on a similar manner?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, and thanks for mentioning your cross-post. This question would have been [off-topic on Stack Overflow](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777) because there is no specific programming problem to be solved — you're just asking for an opinion on something that already works.

Comment: That said, there isn't much code here to review. You may or may not get an answer.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear for me. This is from a minimal example I made and I only posted the code that is relevant to my question..

Comment: This being Code Review and not Stack Overflow, I encourage you to post more code — perhaps even all of it.

Comment: This would be like trying to teach an old dog new tricks, but I will keep your advice in mind..!!